# Get User in method or constructor in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an Asp.Net Core API controller where I use the following method to get the user instance:

```
 var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

I want to know, is it better to assign the logged in user to the user variable in the controller or do I do that in every method?

Please that some methods may have [Authorize] attribute on them.

Thank you

Comment: You can't await inside a constructor. On top of that, please read the help center articles on how to ask a good question. Asking for opinions is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers will be created as short-lived objects whenever a route is accessed. So technically, there is no difference from running some code in the constructor or in *every* action.

That being said, you cannot `await` in constructors, so this is likely more suited for the actions. Also, by not having this in the constructor, you are giving the actions the *choice* to do this when they actually need it, instead of running it all the time.

Even if you end up getting the user object in every action, just consider having a form post where you first validate stuff: You can validate the posted view model *before* retrieving the user object, so you could show an error without actually having to look up the user at all. So only get the user when you actually need it.